# create a batch file to get a ip address from a network interface name

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have servers with more than 2 network interfaces.
ie. Primary.nic, BEN.nic, HB.nic etc

Using the following lines I'm getting the IP from the last NIC:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| find "IP" ^| find "Address" ^| find /v "v6"') do (
    set IPAddr=%%a
)
echo=%IPAddr%
```

I need to find the IP address from a specific NIC name ie. "BEN"

I've tried this too:

```
@echo on
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set result=false
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| "BEN.NIC" ^| find "IP Address"') do (
    set IPAddr=%%a
)
echo %IPAddr%
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: `ipconfig` does not show the IP address and network adapter name on a single line.  The batch file operates on individual lines so you won't be able to get it with this kind of for loop. You might need to write a small program to parse the ipconfig output more nicely than a batch file will permit.

Answer (score 1):

Next script should work:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "nicFunName=wiredEthernet"
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in (
  `wmic nic where "NetConnectionID='%nicFunName%'" get index /value^|find "="`) do (
    rem echo G %%G
    for /F "tokens=*" %%H in ("%%G") do (
        rem echo H %%H
        for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%I in (
            `wmic NICCONFIG where %%H get IPAddress /value`
        ) do (
            rem echo I %%I
            for /F "tokens=1,2 delims={,}" %%J in ("%%I") do (
                echo IPv4=%%J IPv6=%%K
                rem or without double quotes: echo IPv4=%%~J IPv6=%%~K
            ) 
        )
    )   
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Where the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the NIC index in `Index=0` format applicable as next `wmic` query `where` clause condition
- `%%H` to remove a superabundand and harmful carriage return (`0x0D`) from `wmic` output
- `%%I` to retrieve the `IPAddress` by index in `{"<ipv4>","<ipv6>"}` format
- `%%J` to split previous output

You could add a most outer loop as follows:

```
for %%m in (
    "Primary.nic" "BEN.nic" "HB.nic"
) do (
      rem all for... code here  with 
      rem                                where "NetConnectionID='%%~m'"
      rem or call a subroutine or call a batch etc.
)
```